# Converting double to string return strange value in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I have an `NSDictionary` which consist of multiple key/pair values. One of them consist `double` value.

```
NSNumber *goalValue = [info objectForKey:@"goalValue"];
```

I put breakpoint and I found that `goalValue` store the normal value that I need.
[image]

and just below I convert it to `NSSting` like

```
NSString *stringValue=[goalValue stringValue];
```

and this `stringValue` store very strange value.

[image]

Guys please help me. I am totally puzzled, I did goggle but nothing change. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: 98.1 probably is only a rounded value... and the real value in double is what you get. There is finite precision and infinite values between 0.0 and 0.9... so what is the goal and why are you converting to string?

Comment: [Maybe this other question will help][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16096789/nsnumber-stringvalue-different-from-nsnumber-value

Comment: @Volker I have to display in a label.

Comment: Use `NSNumberFormatter`, available since iOS 2.0. Exactly what you need and want, since it deals with localization of decimal separators very well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method `stringValue` will convert the `NSNumber` to string by internally calling [`descriptionWithLocale:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/nsnumber_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000178-descriptionWithLocale_) with locale as `nil` and this method in turn will call `initWithFormat:locale:`,

From Apple docs,

> To obtain the string representation, this method invokes NSString’s initWithFormat:locale: method, supplying the format based on the type the NSNumber object was created with:

[image]

So format specifier used for `double` is `%0.16g`(i.e. 16 digit precision) hence the value `98.09999999999999`

I'd suggest using `NSNumberFormatter`,

```
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[numberFormatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2]; //2 decimal places, change this as required.
NSString *string = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:goalValue];
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I think that [label.setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g", goalValue]]; works too.

Comment: @ali59a That will cause 2 conversions `goalValue` to `double` and then to `NSString`. You need to pass `[goalValue doubleValue]` in that call. Right?

Comment: @Amar Yes, in fact. In this case : [label.setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g", [goalValue doubleValue]]]; No ?

Answer (score 0):

To prevent this behavior, I suggest using NSDecimalNumber (also this is from my experience best format when dealing with very precise amounts)

```
NSDecimalNumber *doubleDecimal = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithDouble:[info objectForKey:@"goalValue"]];
```

for two digits formatting, use numberFormatter

```
NSNumberFormatter * nf = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
 [nf setMinimumFractionDigits:2];
 [nf setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
NSString *stringValue  = [nf stringFromNumber:doubleDecimal]
```

Answer (score -1):

Its showing the rounded value so you can round the value to single digit using `NSNumberFormatter`.

```
 NSNumberFormatter *fomatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [fomatter setMaximumSignificantDigits:2];

    NSString *stringValue=[fomatter stringFromNumber:goalValue];
```

Comment: Have you tried it? cause its shows error `No visible @interface for NSNumberFormatter declare the selector 'setFormat:'`